# how to map a data field starting with a number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

i am maping over some data coming from an API in react and rendering them as crypto stats. one of the data field start with a number.  like this
24hVolume: "26522439016" as obvious it would give an error like this
Line 33:55:  Parsing error: Identifier directly after number. (33:55);
is there any way to overcome this issue?

//i have created an array of all the fields that I am mapping over and rendering as crypto stats. cryptodetails data is coming from an API.

```
const stats = [
```

{ title: 'Price to USD', value: `$ ${cryptoDetails.price && millify(cryptoDetails.price)}`, icon:  },
{ title: 'Rank', value: cryptoDetails.rank, icon:  },
{ title: '24h Volume', value: `$ ${cryptoDetails.volume && millify(cryptoDetails.volume)}`, icon:  },
{ title: 'Market Cap', value: `$ ${cryptoDetails.marketCap && millify(cryptoDetails.marketCap)}`, icon:  },
{ title: 'All-time-high(daily avg.)', value: `$ ${millify(cryptoDetails.allTimeHigh.price)}`, icon:  },
];

/////and then maping over like this

```
 {stats.map(({icon, title, value}) =>(
                    <Col className="coin-stats">
                        <Col className="coin-stats-name">
                            <Text>{icon}</Text>
                            <Text>{title}</Text>
                        </Col>
                        <Text className="stats">{value}</Text>
                    </Col>
                ))}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using. It's impossible to say what's going on from your description

Comment: @msmoore i have added the code, please take a look..

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest iterating it using Object.entries and converting the key into a String.

`const mockData = {
24hVolume: "26522439016",
12hVolume: "26522436381"
}

const ArsedMap = Object.entries(mockData).map(([key, value]) => {key}:{value})`

I hope this helps

Comment: its not working... getting the same error:  Parsing error: Identifier directly after number.

Comment: after some research i found that, i can use bracket notation to access the property starting with a numerical like this.
cryptoDetails["24hVolume"] ;

Comment: Yes, you can do that, and also for other types of keys with a hyphen like `objectName['example-key']`